# Best way to move logical drive to a physical drive

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi

I have a Windows Server 2003 instance which was once running on physical hardware but now runs on vmware esxi. Disk 0 was once a physical RAID, but is now a vmware virtual hd with a primary partition for the C drive and a second logical drive for the E drive.

Enlarging the VMWare virtual disk is easy, but I'm having trouble extending the E drive. Diskpart.exe won't let me use the "extend" command as it is a logical drive.

I'd rather avoid third party stuff like partition magic as it is an important server and I don't want to risk anything strange happening.

Is there an easy way to move a logical drive to a physical drive?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional virtual disk, mount and format it. Start the server in safe mode and run `robocopy` with the `/mir` switch to mirror the contents between the two drives. Then, in diskmgmt.msc unmount the logical drive and change the letter of the new drive to E: and reboot. If everything works fine, then you can delete the logical partition and either shrink the virtual disk or extend the C: partition.

Comment: Or would this be a prime candidate for volume shadow copy?

Comment: Yeah, you could use VSC or even Windows Backup (which leverages VSC) to do this too. There are probably at least half a dozen ways to do this.

Comment: I'd suggest hiding the original E: partition while testing the new drive. I've had strange things happen in such situations with the extra partition still visible to the OS. This also let's you back out easily. Delete the partition when you're confident it's no longer needed.

Comment: Isnt that what I suggested? :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to simply V2V the server, install converter on the server and convert each partition to it's own physical disk.